# Is it possible to have two Android phones with a single phone number?

Tags: sms

Specifically, I am currently using a Samsung S6, but would like a second S6 that would share the texting across both devices.  If one phone texted someone it would appear on the other phone as if that phone had sent/received the text and vice/versa.

I'm assuming that this would mean that the two devices would need to share the same phone number, but I'm open to other options of sharing the same texting on two devices, and I'm open to other devices besides the S6 as well.

Comment: Google Voice would make this possible, if that's an option.

Comment: There are other ways to sync texts too, but one device would be the primary and the other would be sending/receiving through it.  You can't have both phones on the network with the same number unless you duplicated the SIM card, which would just ensure neither phone worked properly.

Comment: For "sharing the same phone number", some providers offer a special SIM. But that wouldn't mean a message *sent* from one device appearing on the other one as sent as well (though it might work for incoming messages). Intention behind that "secondary SIM" mainly is two devices reacting on incoming calls. You'd rather need some "message syncing tool" like [Forward SMS texting w/ 2 phones](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mysms.android.mirror) or [mySMS Sync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mysms.android.sms).

Comment: Tried [Pushbullet?](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pushbullet.android)